# Spark set executor's class loader

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have some `RDD[String]` and I need  to perform some filtering on this RDD. I also have

```
public class MyCustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader { }
```

So it looks something like the following:

```
val rdd: RDD[String] = //...
rdd.filter(str => {
    //Here I need to set Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader() 
    //to MyCustomClassLoader
})
```

Is it possible to do so and avoid calling to `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(myCustomClassLoader)` on each `RDD` record. It's too expensive in my case.

I'm aware that Spark's `CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend` uses either `ChildFirstURLClassLoader` or `MutableURLClassLoader`.

Is there a way to override it?

***UPD***: For some performance reasons I generated `Class` dynamically with `ASM`. So on the driver side I have a bunch of `Class` objects which represents subclasses of `Function[String, AnyRef]`. I need to deliver them on executors and load correctly.

Comment: maybe use `.mapPartitions`

This will at least let you do the classloader stuff executor-local once per partition

    `rdd.mapPartition(
        partition => {
             //classloaderstuff
             partition.filter(...)
        }
    )`

Comment: @DominicEgger Are you sure that it will guarantee that the `Thread.currentThread` used in `mapPartition` are the same as in the `filter`?

Comment: @DominicEgger It would be nice if I can configure the class loader through some spark.properties. Maybe there is a configuration option?

Comment: everything within `mapPartition` should be executor local so my guess would be that the classloader would apply for filter on the iterator but you'll have to verify

Comment: @DominicEgger Once/Twice/..10 times verification does not prove anything unfortunately. I checked sources. Class loader is set each time we submit a task to some executor. Different tasks maybe be submitted by different threads

Comment: maybe you can tell some more about the usecase? why are you switching out the classloader at all?

Comment: @DominicEgger updated my question.

Comment: Hey @St.Antario, Did you get to solution of this problem? I am having the same problem statement, if possible would you share how you handled this case?